# How to create multiple projects with same name in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am new to eclipse and learning Eclipse with version Eclipse Indigo JAVA EE IDE.

I want to create multiple projects with same name in same workspace, is it possible?
If yes how to create multiple projects with same name?

Thanks, 
Yogesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>project name is the same as the folder name, and you cannot have two folders with the same name, so it is definitely impossible</strike>

**UPDATE**

see comments below

Comment: This is incorrect. There is no mandate that the project name must be the same as the folder name. Plus, within the same workspace, it's possible to have projects from different locations in the file system.

Comment: Isaac is absolutely right. This answer is definitely wrong and should thus not be the accepted answer at all. Especially since no counter argument was given since Isaac pointed out the wrongs.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible with Eclipse (Indigo or below). You can't have 2 projects with the same name.

Comment: Why is that? What is the limiting factor? Why do you think so? Got any official documentation specifying this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it depends on your version?  Since I tend to keep my code out of the actual 'workspace' folder, I often have multiple projects with the same name (but different version, for instance).

If you run into that case, you can rename your project - right click it, choose 'rename' (or refactor -> rename, seems to depend on version), and give it a new name.  That doesn't modify the folder's name, but it changes the project name in the .project file in its folder.  After that you can import another project of the same name with no hassles.

Comment: So, are you saying “no, it is not possible”?

Comment: @Kissaki it depends on the goal :)  same folder name + different location on HD -> possible because you can rename the project, but definitely annoying / a pain, and might cause headaches with a team + version control because you'll be modifying the .project file.  this lets you import multiple normally-conflicting projects.  if you *must* have the project names be the same (say, rigid build tools), then I don't *think* it's possible within a single Eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 projects that have the same folder name, but a different project name in Eclipse.

See [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18923211/1412656) for more details:

Answer (score 0):

When the project is initially imported or created in Eclipse the project name is the same as the folder name. But you can rename a project by selecting the project, right click/rename or press F2. This way you can have multiple projects matching the folder name.